# Return After Failed Login Attempt PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am developing login form In PHP
The form is as follows

```
<form method="post" action="Login.php" id="Log">
<select id="Login" name="Type">
<option value="Sel" selected="selected">Select Login type</option>
<option value="Student">Student</option>
<option value="Faculity">Faculity</option>
</select>
<div id="type">
<p id="Ch">Group Id: &nbsp;<input id="l" name="log" type="text"/></p>
<p id="Pass">Password: &nbsp; <input id="p" name="Pass" type="password" /></p>
<input id="Cond" type="Text" />
<input type="submit" value="Login"  />
<p id="Invalid" style="padding-top:.75em; color:#FF0000;">Invalid Login Or Password</p>
</form>
```

In post.php I connect with database and check login and passwords.

I want to show the `<p id="invalid">` tag when password or login don't match in the same form below it without any delay.

The `<p id="invalid">` is hidden at the beginning and only be shown when login or pasword is incorrect

How can I achieve this/ connect with database through PHP?

Comment: One option is ajax, another one is to just display the Invalid message if the login failed. I don't think that there is more to say, just learn same basics...

Comment: Can you please explain what your database looks like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Galen's answer. You should put the login procession stuff on the same page. If you don't know how to do that, you should do this:

```
<?php
$itswrong = false;
if (isset($_POST['Pass']) && isset($_POST['log'])) {
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM your_database_name WHERE group_id = '{$_POST['log']}' AND password = SHA1('{$_POST['Pass']}')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
// Match was found!
// Do whatever here, e.g. session registering (starting a session), etc.
} else {
// Oh damn, it's wrong!
$itswrong = true;
// Do stuff here
}
} else {
// Move your form in here
}
?>
```

All you need to do in your form is move it to under `// Move your form in here`, change
this:

```
<p id="Invalid" style="padding-top:.75em; color:#FF0000;">Invalid Login Or Password</p>
```

to this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Pass']) && isset($_POST['log']) && $itswrong == true) {
?>
<p id="Invalid" style="padding-top:.75em; color:#FF0000;">Invalid Login Or Password</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

and also change the values in the SQL query to suit your needs. Then it would work. I want you to move the form under `// Move your form in here`, because then if the form is not submitted, it will show.

**EDIT:** Also change the title of your form,

From this:

```
<form method="post" action="Login.php" id="Log">
```

To this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" id="Log">
```

That will make the page just post the data to itself, making my code on top possible.

I do not suggest ajax, as it is WAY harder for hackers to hack into PHP then JavaScript-related technology, as JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side.

Please notify me if you still have problems.

Lucas

Comment: How Can I Change Post Method Of Form Previously It is
<form method="post" action:"login.php">
How To Change Action So That it Evaluates Login Here??

Comment: You should not turn off error reporting with the `@`.  This is poor programming practice, especially during testing phase.  There are better methods for this once your are production.

Comment: Can i make a function in which i can do the server connection in the same file and write method="function name" does it works kindly elaborate i am not getting it
Also What Is Request URI

Comment: @user1366440 `Request` and `SERVER` are global variables used for specific functions. [Check this for SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [Check this for REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) If you don't understand these easy ones, then you should probably start from [the beginning](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to set the form action to the same page that contains the form.  At the beginning of the php page the username/password should be checked so that when the form html is loaded you already know the login result and can display the error.

THEN, if you want to do it without a page reload, you write an AJAX script and hook it to the submit button (and disable the form from submitting)

This way if javascript is disabled everything will still work.

Comment: But Each Group id Has Its Own Unique Passowrd
Until I get Group Id I Am Not Able To Get Password From Database

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example; this is what I use, in a nutshell:

```
$entered_password = $_POST['pword'];
$php_self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if ($password != $entered_password) {
   $error['pword'] = "<span class=\"errormess\">You entered wrong Password</span>";
} else {
    $error['pword'] = "";
}
```

I do this for all my fields, after checking the DB for valid answers, entering a new key into the array if there is an error.  Then in the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $php_self?>">
   <input type="password" name="pword" />
   <?php echo $error['pword']?>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

If there's an error, then it will display under the `<input>`, if not then there is nothing displayed.  In my CSS, the class `errormess` is red/bold letters.  I do this for all the inputs.  If there's an error in any of the fields, I just php_self the page, if no errors then it `header["Location: confirm.html"]` redirects to the appropriate page logging in the user.

This is a very basic, in a nutshell example but hopefully you get the jest of it.

Hope this helps